# rubyで存在しない要素にアクセスしたときに返すデフォルト値を指定するには？

Tags: ruby, coffeescript

coffeescriptで

```
user = if Math.random() > 0.5
  {items:[{place:1000}]}
else
  {items:[{place:1000},{place:2000}]} 

place = user?.items?[1]?.place || 0
console.log place
```

とすると、userオブジェクトの中身がどんなに複雑でも、要素があればその値、無ければ0を取得するということが出来てとても便利だと思っているのですが、これをrubyで実現することは可能なのでしょうか。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ActiveSupport の Object#try を利用すると、同じような事が出来ます。これは、メソッドが無ければ nil を返し、そうで無ければ send と同じ動きをするものです。

```
require "active_support/all"
user = {items:[{place: 1000}]}
# => {:items=>[{:place=>1000}]}

user[:items][1][:place]
# => NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

user.try(:[], :items).try(:[], 1).try(:[], :place)
# => nil
user.try(:[], :items).try(:[], 1).try(:[], :place) || 0
# => 0


user = {items:[{place: 1000}, {place: 2000}]}
user.try(:[], :items).try(:[], 1).try(:[], :place)
# => 2000
user.try(:[], :items).try(:[], 1).try(:[], :place) || 0
# => 2000
```

変数に対しては、`defined?` を利用することになります。(現実的には、変数自体が nil であることがあっても、定義されていないというのはあまり無いと思いますが。)

```
((defined? user) ? user : nil).try(...)
```

または

```
user = nil if not defined? user
```

Comment: すこし気持ち悪い気もしますが、この方法がベターだと思いました。ありがとうございますm(_ _)m

Answer (score 3):

もし遊び心気分なら、`method_missing`などの組み込み関数を使って、いたずらができます。

```
# メソッドがないときに、このクラスが返されます。
class DeadClass
  def method_missing(*args)
    self
  end

  def だ
    nil
  end

  def try_index(*args)
    self
  end
end

# ブラケットがメソッド名に表示するのは不正ですから、このクラスはインデックスのときに返されます。
class Indexer
  def initialize(obj)
    @obj = obj
  end

  def [](*args)
    @obj.try_index(*args)
  end
end

class Object
  def method_missing(name, *args)
    if name.to_s[0] == 'か'
      realname = name.to_s[1..-1].to_sym

      if self.respond_to? realname
        self.send(realname, *args)
      else
        DeadClass.new
      end
    else
      raise NoMethodError.new("NoMethodError")
    end
  end

  def だ
    self
  end

  def か
    Indexer.new(self)
  end

  def try_index(*args)
    if self.respond_to? :"[]"
      self[*args]
    else
      DeadClass.new
    end
  end
end
```

使い方は、「か」とメソッド名前につけて、「だ」と行のあとにつけます。

```
# 「だ」と`nil`か値になります。
1.かsucc.かsucc.だ
# => 3

nil.かsucc.かsucc.だ
# => nil

user = {items:[{place: 1000}]}
user.か[:items].か[1].か[:place].だ || 0
# => 0

user.か[:items].か[0].か[:place].だ || 0
# => 1000
```

Coffeescriptの方がいいけど、上のようにするとRubyでも多かれ少なかれ似せることができます。少なくとも構文がActiveSupportよりいいと思います。

Comment: これはおもしろいですね！若干言語破壊的な気もするので共同開発などで実用的なのか心配になりましたが、そもそもこういうことができる事自体知らなかったので目からウロコです。

Comment: @hojo　私もそう思います。モンキーパッチが共同開発で悪くても実用的じゃなくても、Rubyの表現力のいい立証だと思いましたから、陳列したかったです。

Answer (score 1):

Hashieというgemと`method_missing`（NullObjectパターン）を組み合わせて、CoffeeScriptのシンタックスにできるだけ近づけてみました。

```
require 'hashie'

include Hashie::Extensions::MethodAccess

module NullObject
  refine NilClass do
    def method_missing(m,*a,&b)
      self
    end
  end
end
using NullObject

5.times do
  user = rand > 0.5 ? {items:[{place:1000}]} : {items:[{place:1000},{place:2000}]}
  place = user.items[1].place || 0
  p place
end
```

実行結果

```
2000
0
2000
0
0
```

CoffeeScriptでは `user?.items?[1]?.place || 0` になっていますが、こちらは `user.items[1].place || 0` のように `?` が付かないのがCoffeeScript版と異なる点です。

参考文献

- https://github.com/intridea/hashie
- http://melborne.github.io/2014/03/07/nullobject-pattern-in-ruby/

Answer (score 0):

制御構造のrescue修飾子を利用するのが一番簡単かと思います。http://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/2.1.0/doc/spec=2fcontrol.html#begin の少し下を参照してください。存在しない要素にアクセスした時にデフォルト値を指定するのと少し違いますが、存在しない要素にアクセスした時にnilが返った後の処理で、例外が発生して rescue の後ろの値が返されます。
この書き方では以下で元の動作と同じになります。

```
user = if rand > 0.5
         {items:[{place:1000}]}
       else
         {items:[{place:1000},{place:2000}]}
       end
place = (user[:items][1][:place] rescue nil) || 0
puts place
```